# JavaScript: Sorting items in each column

Tags: javascript

I have an array list sorted by number, that shows X items by row.

```
data.people.sort(function (a, b) {

    return a.grade - b.grade;

});
```

There are two numbers in each item from an array. The current grid is sorted (in rows) by the first number. Now, I would like to sort (vertically) the result of each column by the second number.

Comment: You want to sort horizontally by number. What do you want to sort on vertically? And can you give a code example?

Comment: If you sort the list by number both horizontally and vertically, then just having the list sorted will be enough to have the correct order.

Comment: Is this a 2D array or do you need a sort based on an arbitrary row length? Also sorting vertically will undo your number sorting by row. Is that acceptable or is there some constraints that keep the number ordering in some way?

Comment: @TobiObeck, there are two numbers below each name. The current grid is sorted by the first number. Now, I would like to sort the columns by the second number.

Comment: So to be clear this is a 2 phase sort. First horizontally by first number, then vertically by the second?

Comment: For example, the first column, must be: Hannah (1.53), Tommy (1.74), Mark (1.83), Zack (1.85).

Comment: You will have to make a custom sort function.

Comment: MrJman006, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sort that works based off an arbitrary row length.

```
// Your array here.
var arr = [
    {first: 1, second: 5},{first: 2, second: 1},{first: 3, second: 6},
    {first: 4, second: 2},{first: 5, second: 2},{first: 6, second: 3},
    {first: 7, second: 3}
];

// Your row length here.
var rowLen = 3;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
var colLen = Math.ceil(arr.length / rowLen);


console.log("original");
showArr(arr, rowLen);

for(var curCol = 0; curCol < rowLen; curCol++)
{
    // Standard insertion sort on colums.
    for(var i = 0; i < colLen - 1; i++)
    {
        for(var j = i + 1; j < colLen; j++)
        {
            if(j * rowLen + curCol < arr.length)
            {   
                var colIdxI = i * rowLen + curCol;
                var colIdxJ = j * rowLen + curCol;
                if(comparitor(arr[colIdxI].second, arr[colIdxJ].second) == 1)
                {
                    // Swap.
                    var temp = arr[colIdxI];
                    arr[colIdxI] = arr[colIdxJ];
                    arr[colIdxJ] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log("sorted");
showArr(arr, rowLen);

function comparitor(a, b)
{
  if (a < b)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

function showArr(arr, rowLen)
{
    var set;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(i % rowLen == 0)
        {
            console.log(set);
            set = "";
        }

        set += JSON.stringify(arr[i]) + " ";
    }

    if(arr.length % rowLen != 0)
    {
        console.log(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you MrJman! It's working!

Comment: No problem. If its the one that you ended up using, you could accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function custom_sort (_arr, columnCount) {
  var cols,c,arr2,arr = _arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.grade - b.grade;
  });

  cols = [];
  for(c = 0; c < columnCount-1; c+=1) {
    cols.push([]);
  }

  arr.forEach(function (e,i) {
    var c = i%columnCount;
    cols[c].push(arr[i]);
  });

  cols.map(function (e,i) {
    return cols[c].sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.otherVal - b.otherVal;
    });
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
    var c = i%columnCount, l = Math.floor(i/columnCount);
    arr2.push(cols[c][l]);
  }

  return arr2;
}

...

custom_sort(data.people, 5);
```